# How can i make a easy op amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, speakers

I wanna make a easy 2~5watts speaker. 
- use op amp (don't use audio amp)

here's circuit i made. [image]
and i can't solve the error...

how can i make a easier one? I really need your help!

Comment: Your signal source V2 is shorted out to ground.

Comment: your D1 is shorted to output and should be 4 diodes since you have 4 diode drops in two TIPxx's. Crossover distortion is an issue with low gain, so bias is usually controlled with a pot and D1 diodes are thermally coupled to heatsink..

Comment: Also, that's a very strange output stage, with one of the transistors reversed...

Comment: *What* error?  You haven't said what is not working as intended.  This really should be obvious.

Comment: You can start by fixing R6, Q1, Q4 and D1. And that's just for starters.

Comment: Provide some discussion about how you approached your design!! MORE WORDS! It's hard to figure out how to best help you if we don't know how you were thinking about things. And also what you consider to be problems with what you have! And do you want an opamp, or not? The schematic says no. But your words aren't clear.

Comment: This is some kind of comedy circuit right? Engineering requires attention to detail and if you applied this little attaention to say driving a car, you'd be crashing every 50 metres. Where did you find this trainwreck schematic?

Comment: @Andyaka He says, "here's circuit i made," so I'm perhaps assuming too much by thinking he cobbled this up somehow on his own? Unfortunately, he provides no evidence of his thinking. So hard to know.

Comment: If this was a where's Goldbug or Waldo for each mistake, I can count a dozen. hehe

Comment: To add to @WhatRoughBeast's list: R1, R2, R7, R10, C2, C4, C5, ...

Comment: Oh yes, and you might want to disconnect your input from ground. I mean, just on general principles, right? It's hard to amplify a signal which is forced to be zero.

Comment: I'd look up "common emitter amplifier" and "push-pull amplifier" on the net to understand how they work, and never short-circuit the input.

Answer (score 1):

Distortion is determined by output current and crossover glitch.

Understand the differences between your circuit and this one. You may reduce supply voltage and use your TIPxx on outputs and bias input to single supply to V+/2 with more caps or use split supply.

[image]
Here I have added pointers to DC bias , internal compensation 1st order filter (integrator) for stability in closed loop gain like Op Amp with R ratios.
The output Vbe drops on 3 transistors is compensated by 2 diodes and a controlled current on 2.2K to eliminate crossover .  The 2 NPN's only amplify the positive wave, while the PNP amplifies the -ve wave, with the bottom right 2N3055 to make a better PNP Darlington.

[image]

this next one has less performance but simpler and values are critical.
[image]

Comment: It might help if you explained the first one, in getting the OP to understand it. For example, why the VAS (BD139 with emitter at -35V) has the 220pF capacitance added from base to collector (Miller.) Or how the negative feedback network would be designed. Etc. Improvements that might be made to the long tailed pair... There are all kinds of educational opportunities here. Nothing written at all about any of them. Answers should provide some basic teaching, IMO.

Comment: okie dokie ..... I'll do a pictoral illustration.

Comment: Now he can ask better questions

Comment: Hehe! I suppose so!

Comment: Hmm. Just curious, Tony. But those emitter resistors of \$.33\:\Omega\$ might drop like \$2\:\textrm{V}\$ at an \$I_{PK}=7\:\textrm{A}\$. Are they where you want them?

Comment: dear @jonk , Thankyou for bringing this to my attention. ;) We must accept that Class AB is at best 30% lossy and to improve linearity a bit more it helps in this power range to rely on linear 10W emitter resistors or < 5% of the peak power rather than the nonlinear lower Vbe junction resistance. The 100W 4 Ohm load is done with 28Vp thus a 7 V extra drop from 34-to zero makes the 2V look small , but the headroom is needed to provide 100W power for 8 Ohm speakers.       Feel free to suggest a performance improvement without a major layout or component change.  We value employee suggestions.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you have enough base separation in your output BJTs. Do you think so?

Comment: crossover step is reduced by open loop gain but adding another diode may be too much on quiescent output current draw. certainly sub-optimal.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose I need to sit down and analyze it, then. In general, at 100W rated output anyway, I wouldn't expect to see .33 Ohm emitter resistors. Perhaps .1 Ohm. More likely .05 Ohm, I think. 2V pk drop, plus three Vbe's, is ... a lot to separate the bases. Negative feedback with lots of open loop gain to waste helps. But now I'm looking back at the long tailed pair and the VAS and wondering... Oh, well. When I get a moment....

Comment: Yes I would use 30x more open loop gain and balanced bias derived from input current source with Re= 33mOhm

Comment: It seems the only way to reduce Re is add more stages of hFE to avoid THD rise due to rE

Comment: thank you!! That information is helpful for me! and i'm going to try now! xD

Comment: yeah!!!!!!!! i did it i did it !!! 
thank YOU! Tony

Comment: yeah ! one small step for man...

Answer (score 1):

A design like this probably starts with your description of the required output power. This determines your voltage rails and current requirements. Start here:

$$ V_{pk} = \sqrt{2 P R}$$

From this, and your \$2\:\textrm{W}\$ to \$5\:\textrm{W}\$ specification added to the apparent \$8\:\Omega\$ requirement for your speaker, I find that \$V_{pk} = 5.7\:\textrm{V}\$ @ \$708\:\textrm{mA}\$ to \$V_{pk} = 9\:\textrm{V}\$ @ \$1120\:\textrm{mA}\$. To keep the power BJTs out of saturation, you'll need to add about \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ to each rail.

Since 16 VAC CT transformers are pretty common, and since you didn't specify that much here, that's what I'd go for. You'd need to find one rated for \$1.4\:\textrm{A}\$ (a 1.6 derating multiplier because of the peak currents required) or something around \$25\:\textrm{VA}\$ or better. You should be able to achieve \$7\:\textrm{V}\$ @ \$900\:\textrm{mA}\$ into your load with the rail voltage being a minimum of \$8\:\textrm{V}\$. With a filter capacitor of \$4700\:\mu\textrm{F}\$ the ripple will be about \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ above that minimum. In short, the rail would vary from \$8\:\textrm{V}\$ to \$9\:\textrm{V}\$ under a full average load of \$900\:\textrm{mA}\$. Peak currents through the bridge rectifier diodes will be about \$6\:\textrm{A}\$, so make sure you get a bridge capable of that.

(This is probably over-kill, since the average current load with a real signal will be less. I estimated the above with a constant DC load current. The RMS load current will be less and you could probably get by using 12.6 VAC CT. But this guarantees that you can drive and hold the output per specs without getting into the input signal details.)

So now you have enough to make some decisions about a transformer (12.6 VAC CT or 16 VAC CT), a bridge rectifier, and a filter capacitor. And you now have a basic linear power supply and an idea of what kind of rails you are dealing with. You could squander more money on a bigger filter capacitor. But since I computed things based upon a constant DC load and the RMS current will be less, anyway, the ripple will be pretty low in practice. But you could add some nice regulators for the (+) and (-) side. And, at least, you'd have an idea about how to select those. You may need to raise the rails still more, though, to cover the drops required by your regulators.

Let's assume a 12.6 VAC CT transformer rated at \$\ge 13\:\textrm{VA}\$ (\$I_{pk}=900\:\textrm{mA}\$.) This should easily sustain \$\pm 8\:\textrm{V}\$ at the two rails and gives you a power rating of \$3\:\textrm{W}\$. Those transformers are easily found, too. So this is good.

Hmm. Seems like we haven't even gotten to the amplifier, yet. But that's because it's important to have an idea of what your supply rails will look like. So you look at your voltage requirements, add some headroom for your output driver BJTs, and massage the numbers around a bit. You don't just slap on some HUGE power supply rails, if you don't need them. So you really do need to start with specifying and detailing out your power supply design first. The rest will follow.

There are a number of output topologies to go for. But let's stay with the one you picked, using the TIP31 and TIP32 BJTs. They come in different \$V_{CEO}\$ ratings. But all of them will work in this case. So let's just use that.

Now, let's assume you have two rails: \$\pm 8\:\textrm{V}\$. Plus ground, of course. Walk me through a design of just your output stage alone. This should be relatively easy to do. Explain all of the details you are thinking about in laying it out and refer to the datasheet for the TIP31 and TIP32 as you go, as well. Work out how you will avoid cross-over distortion, how you will estimate and deal with power dissipation, how you will compensate for variability in \$V_{BE}\$ over temperature, etc.

Keep in mind this is just the two output BJTs and a very basic walk through of your thinking here. This will help a great deal in working out the rest.

Once you do that, I think others can comment on that part. The other thing you need to do is to work out the 1st stage, as well. Do you use a long-tailed pair? (Not a bad idea.) But again, how do you design it? What trade-offs are you making, and why? You also need to worry about your global negative feedback network. How do you design that and why do you make the choices you make? And how to do you design the intermediate VAS, which translates between the 1st input stage and your 3rd output stage? What considerations are you making here, too?

The gist of all this is that all you've done is slap out a design that can't work, as shown. And you admit it has problems. But you've said nothing at all about what you were thinking in producing it. Did you just copy it from somewhere? Is this a Frankenstein schematic that is some patched together composite, where you understood little about your stitching of things together?

You should probably break your question up into individual parts. Start with your thinking about the power supply design. Make that a single question, work through the details leading up to a complete design and ask for input. Then do the same for your output stage. Then do the same for your input stage. Then do the same for the VAS stage. Then, you may be able to pull all that together into a coherent final question, which now includes your global negative feedback as well, that puts all of these pieces together and asks if you got that right, as well.